# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar todos los elementos de una página muy grande?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando tomar, de Deezer, todas canciones que tengo en mi playlist para buscarlas en youtube y poder oírlas desde mi pc. Pensé que sería tan fácil como

```
document.getElementsByClassName("JoTQr") //siendo "JoTQr" la clase que contiene la estructura de las canciones y sus atributos (entre esas, el título)
```

Pero al hacer esto solo me carga las primeras 15 coincidencias (cuando debían ser 404).
Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que se cargue toda la página para tomar todos los valores que necesito?

Comment: Es posible que se este usando una paginación ya que por lo general no se suele pedir una gran cantidad de datos en una petición `http`.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna forma de "forzar" esto para que me las entregue todas?